# read file from today and yesterday in PHP

Tags: php

I need to open 2 files from my filesystem. Both files are csv-files. I need to determine the differences from both files: So I need to check, how the content has changed from yesterday compared to today.

There will be exactly 1 file every day. The files are labeled according to the timestamp, so there is no real pattern. (to clarify, yea, it is the unix timestamp, but the file isn't created everyday at the exact same time) For example, the file for yesterday is called: *file-1601926309814.csv*, the one from the day before (since there is no file created for today yet): *file-1601847963649.csv*.

I was looking around and found [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php), but I'm not sure if that helps that much. Another option I came up with, was checking with `glob` which files are in the directory, but I'm not sure if that is a good solution.

My code so far:

```
<?php

// Simple script to determine a negative Delta between 2 files
// These 2 files are taken from a given destination and pushed
// through an array diff. The result will be written in a new 
// file.

$path = "G:\\interfaces\\out\\SAP\\Shopartikel\\";
$sFileYesterday  = "testfile_1.csv";
$sFileToday      = "testfile_2.csv";

$aItemsYesterday = array();
$aItemsToday     = array();
$aOutput         = array();

// get all files from yesterday
$fHandleYesterday = fopen($path.$sFileYesterday, "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($fHandleYesterday, 0, ";")) !== false) {
    $aItemsYesterday[] = $line[0];
}

// get all files from today
$fHandleToday = fopen($path.$sFileToday, "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($fHandleToday, 0, ";")) !== false) {
    $aItemsToday[] = $line[0];
}

// determine the difference
$aOutput = array_diff($aItemsYesterday, $aItemsToday);

var_dump($aOutput);
```

As mentioned above, the output is correct, but I need to fetch the correct files as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe there is a pattern to those filenames... https://3v4l.org/quSmQ

Comment: well.. tunnelvision. obviously unix-timestamp. But the problem is, that I don't know the filenames (yet). If I have the file already, I could already work with it. I don't know if it is safe to assume, that I can simply divide by 1000 and rely on the first digits, leaving out the last ones. If I reverse that and would get the current timestamp and add 1 day on top of it, it might still not match the filename, since it includes seconds from the creation-time and my script would use the timestamp from the execution time.

Comment: Se my answer below. You rename all the files in the folder before you start the rest of the code.

Comment: Is "file-" part of the file name?

Comment: What's the exact problem here? What makes you think that `array_diff` can only work with "static filenames"?

Comment: For reading a directory, look at [`opendir`](https://www.php.net/opendir). You still need to [`stat`](https://www.php.net/stat) the files to determine the file's timestamp.

Comment: @NicoHaase no no, array_diff will work just fine, I just need to determine the correct files.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the relevant information in understandable form. Its better to skip the rest which is not that relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could organize the files in the folder while you are at it anyways.

Use glob as you suggested to get all all filenames and iterate through them and change the names of those with a UNIX timestamp to a date timestamp.

```
$path = "path";

foreach (glob($path . "*.csv") as $filename) {
    // only rename files that have not been renamed before. 
    if(strlen($filename) == 17){  // assumes the filename is [UNIX].csv
         rename($path . $filename, $path . date("Y-m-d", (int)$filename/1000));
    }
}
```

This should rename the files to their date and make it easy to pick the correct ones.

An alternative way if you don't want to rename the files is to create a "translation table" array of the Y-m-d date as key and UNIX name as value.

That way you know $arr["2020-10-06"] is todays file whatever the UNIX timestamp is.

```
$path = "path";

foreach (glob($path . "*.csv") as $filename) {
    $arr[date("Y-m-d", (int)((int)substr($filename, -17)/1000))] = $path . $filename;
}

$sFileYesterday  = $arr[date("Y-m-d", time()-86400)];
$sFileToday      = $arr[date("Y-m-d", time())];
```

This code will become slower and slower for each day since there is one more file each day it needs to "translate".
You could perhaps speed that up by saving the json of your translation array and find the "new" file using array_diff or something.
Not sure it will be faster than iterating the array and doing the "translation" but you will have to see when it becomes slow.

Example: https://3v4l.org/cb4Mp

Comment: I'd really not rename the files, since they will be used from other systems as well. The filenames include a unix-timestamp, but doesn't only include it, for example: "web_assortment-1601926309814.csv". I mean, I could simply parse the timestamp in it, but renaming would really be a last-resort option.

Comment: works perfectly fine and is easily readable + maintainable. Thank you!